# Confusion regarding understanding the explanation given by Purcell in the example of two cavites inside a spherical conductor

Tags: electrostatics

In the example shown in Purcell Example of two spherical cavities in a sphere . It was written in the explanation that :.

> Now let's look at the conductor $A$. Since the total charge on $A$ is zero, a charge of $q_{b}+q_{c}$ must be distributed over its outside surface, to balance the $-q_{b}$ and $-q_{c}$ charges on the surfaces of the cavities. If $q_{d}$ were absent, the field outside $A$ would be the symmetrical radial field, $E=\left(q_{b}+q_{c}\right) / 4 \pi \epsilon_{0} r^{2}$, with the charge $q_{b}+q_{c}$ uniformly distributed over the outside surface.**The distribution would indeed be uniform because the field inside the material of the conductor is zero, and because we are assuming that there is no charge external to the conductor.** The setup is therefore spherically symmetric, as far as the outside surface of the conductor is concerned. (Any effect of the interior charges on the outside surface charge can be felt only through the field. And since the field is zero just inside the outside surface, there is therefore no effect.).

- I understand field is zero inside when the both $q_d$ and $q_b+q_c$ induce charge was not there . But when we slowly first add the induce $q_b+q_c$ charge , why it has to give a electric field of zero everywhere in the (inside of conductor material and also in the cavities) in the inside ?                          (Note : i am talking of a field contribution from the $q_b+q_c$ induce charge not the net field which is already we know in the inside the material of conductor should be zero .).
- And another question is whether a uniform distribution over a sphere is the only possible way by which a zero field (due to those charge distribution on surface) can be generated all over the inside of the sphere ?